# vba wrong pivot notation

Tags: vba, pivot, notation

Something wrong with my pivot notation
2 line shows an error but if I put "4" instead of "lastRow" it works. What am I doing wrong?. How to change fixed range into dynamic?

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Sheet1!R1C1:R10C" & "lastRow")
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(Range("I2"))
```

Comment: lastRow is ofcourse defined lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: `"Sheet1!R1C1:R10C" & "lastRow"` is the same as `"Sheet1!R1C1:R10ClastRow"`. You probally want `"Sheet1!R1C1:R10C" & lastRow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quote around lastrow:

```
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Sheet1!R1C1:R10C" & lastRow)
```